# Subclassing an NSScrollView's DocumentView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsscrollview, nsshadow

How can one subclass an NSScrollView's DocumentView in order to do some custom drawing? I need to do some work with NSShadow inside of the scroll view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document view is just a normal view (subclass of `NSView`,) so all you have to do is to create a view, either programmatically or in Interface Builder, and set the scroll view's `documentView` property to the new view.

You can set the property in a suitable `awakeFromNib` method, for instance.